# How to parse JSON array in android?[JSON structure below in description]

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have an Json Array Like -

```
[
  500,
  "Applied Before"
]
```

How can I parse it in android.

Comment: What u have tried?

Comment: I'm confused - is that possible to parse in json?

Comment: why is there no key value pair there?

Comment: Yes Possible, String is simple JSONArray. just do it as `JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(pass_json_string_here);` and use for-loop to get all value from `arr`. or if JSONArray contains only two values then do it as `int intValue=arr.optInt(0); String strValue=arr.optString(1);`

Comment: Thank you so much.....this is works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
 String data = " [500," +
            "  \"Applied Before\"] ";
    try {
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(data);
        Log.i("arr",""+arr.get(0));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Improper JSON Array syntax .

Example of a JSON Array :

```
"employees":[
        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
        {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
    ]
```

Comment: Try- http://jsonlint.com/ --link for check your json data is validate or not.

Comment: how about this of your code -                                               {"employees": [{
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
 "firstName": "Anna",
 "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
 "firstName": "Peter",
 "lastName": "Jones"
}]}